# Windows 7 x64 support for Intel GMA 3650 (or GMA 3600)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, 64-bit

I recently purchased an Intel D2700 MUD motherboard and I cannot find drivers for the Win7 x64 integrated graphics (Intel GMA 3650 aka PowerVR sgs545). The accompanying CD contains Win7 x32 version only. When I run it I got an error:

> This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing
>   the software.

I tried to use online utility [Intel Driver Update Utility Graphics](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics). I used Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer without success. First, UAC prompt appear, and then endlessly spinning progress-bar with text "*Analyzing computer...*". The text in UAC prompt is:

> Program file name: System Requirements Lab 
>   Verified publisher: Husdawg, LLC

I downloaded this utility (`intel_srldetect_4.5.5.0`) and started it from my hard disk. I got an error:

> A network error occured while attempting to read from the file:
>   C:\Users\Loom\Downloads\SystemRequirementsLab_intel_4.5.5.0.msi

Standard VGA driver works for this video card but without hardware acceleration:

> Hardware acceleration is either disabled or not supported by your
>   video card driver, which could slow game performance. Make sure you
>   have the latest video card driver installed and that hardware
>   acceleration is turned on.

Where I can get appropriate driver?

***EDIT:***
I installed the 8.15.8.1050 beta (*GFX_Vista_Win7_64_8.15.8.1050_Beta5*) from the **@someonewhoknowsstuff**'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/502795/137847) in safe mode, because in usual mode I've got an error:

> An error occurred while registering one or more components.
>
> Setup will exit.

After installing OS didn't start but began crashing on start with BSOD:

> A problem has been detected and Windows has been shut down to prevent damage
>   to your computer.
>
> imgkmd64.sys
>    DRIVER_UNLOADED_WITHOUT_CANCELLING_PENDING_OPERATIONS
>
> [...]
>
> Technical information:
>   * * * STOP: 0x000000CE (0xFFFFF88007039C68, 0x0000000000000008,
>   0xFFFFF88007039C68, 0x0000000000000000)
>
> imgkmd64.sys

Thus, I forced to remove this driver. (As **@tester** [said](https://superuser.com/a/670903/137847), cause of BSOD is my 4GB RAM. So, reducing amount of memory down to 2GB can make the driver work.)

Comment: Why would you need 64bit OS on a netbook? Most they go up to is 4 gigs of memory. Wouldn't be any faster anyways. Best bet for those puppies is a SSD and 4 gigs and call it quits!

Comment: It may be faster or slower. 64 bit is usually slower do to bigger pointers and more cache misses. However AMD64 (which is what 64 bit intel CPUs use) also has more registers. On average this evens out. As for 64 bit and 4GB. I suggest a 64 bit OS for anything above 512MiB do to ASR issues.

Comment: @Hennes actually on x86_64 cache misses less than on x86 http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~wspires/32bit_versus_64bit_amd64.pdf http://superuser.com/q/638598/241386 probably because they have more registers, less memory access is needed

Answer (score 6):

Intel does not support 64-bit with that motherboard's graphics chipset.  That's the official line.

Judging by version of the existing 32-bit driver (v **8.14.8**.1077), you may be able to get away with using the "[Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 Driver for Windows 7* 64 bit](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=19493&lang=eng)", as it reports "This driver package contains version 15.12.75.50.7.64.2230 (**8.14.10**.2230)".

I've dealt with Intel drivers for many years now, and a) they have a duality when it comes to version numbers, and b) they are very good at bundling similar drivers together.

Often the driver 'version' is the bundle's version (v15.12.xxxx), which contains one or more drivers with their own version numbers (ie v8.14.xxxx); or something to that effect, I've never hammered it down exactly. :)

Unfortunately, if that one doesn't work you may be out of luck.

Comment: Wouldn't the generic display driver be fine in this case?  I mean its not like the chipset is a powerhouse to begin with.

Comment: @Ramhound Perhaps, but the OP was looking for hardware acceleration: "Standard VGA driver works for this video card but without hardware acceleration". :)

Answer (score 4):

[latest edit]

EVRICA!

search google for "GFX_Vista_Win7_64_8.15.8.1050_Beta5". tested on Acer Aspire One D270-26Dkk with Intel atom N2600, 4Gb DDR3 A-data 1333Mhz, under windows 7 Ultimate 64bit.

Good luck!

[previous]

you can force the driver to install editing the .inf file, in this particular case: igdlh64.inf

1. from device manager (Run -> DevMgmt.msc) right click and copy the Hardware ID of the display adapter
2. insert it  (in my case PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_0BE1; you can keep the substring if you want/have it - this is enough to corectly identify the vga onboard) in the [Intel.Mfg.NTamd64] section of the .inf file replacing one, any or even all the existing hardware_IDs, so you will be able to try all the drivers for all the supported boards.
3. replace the mames that will appear after identification with your own in order to be able to test them one by one in the section
   ;
   ; Localizable Strings
   ;
4. manually install the drivers one by one, then restart, and try the next one (this is why you need to give them different names at the end of the .inf file)

if the driver is working with your board, you will see in DevMgmt.msc the message "This device is working properly" otherwise, you will get a 43 code - device was shut down by windows.

good luck trying any driver!

NB: under a 64bit OS, you need x64 drivers for a hardware. you may try to use a virtual machine with win32 installed, but.. what`s the point?

Comment: 8.15.8.1050_Beta5 works fine with 2GB RAM. 4GB can not be used with this driver (BSOD). I have tested it with three different CPU's and two chipsets (ICH10 and NM10), all have the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to give you the bad news, folks!

The so-called "Intel" GMA3600 actually was NOT designed by Intel, but is instead a PowerVR SGV545 licensed from British-based Imagination Technologies (www.ingtec.com/).

While Intel Corporation makes its own graphics programming documentation freely available (https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation), Imagination Technologies considers its own programming documentation "Confidential Information" (a.k.a. military "Top Secret"). Imagination Technologies refuses to provide 64-bit drivers for its PowerVR graphics cores and is jealous of keeping its own documentation strictly under lock and key and of employing the long arm of the law to insist that its documentation remain Top Secret.

Plain and simple, folks. This is why Intel CANNOT produce drivers for the GMA3600 for ANY 64-bit operating system platform, whether it be Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8, open-source Linux, you name it. Period.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really an Intel GPU but an integrated/rebadged PowerVR SGX545, so Intel doesn't seem to have much control over it. They do not make 64-bit drivers for this GPU, and haven't made any plans to do so public.

I'm in the same boat. I'm using a Shuttle XS36V with that CPU, now as a low-power server. The same GPU (albeit slower clocked) was available in an older Atom, and there are still the same issues today with that 32-bit driver. I don't expect much here.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but as Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 released after this post, I decide to test it on it and share my finding:

Win7 x64: Confirmed 2GB ram working, 4GB still testing

Win8.1 x64, win10 x64: all 2GB and 4GB ram lead to BSOD 
using `GFX_Vista_Win7_64_8.15.8.1050`

So, sad to say please just save your time to stick on Windows 7

FYR, tested on zotac zbox id15

Answer (score 0):

Intel recently released a "test" driver for x64 Windows.

> Title: Intel® HD Graphics Test Driver for Windows 7 & *Windows 8* 64 (zip)
>
> Date:09/24/2012
>
> Version:15.28.6.64.2857
>
> Operating Systems:Windows 7 (64-bit), *Windows 8, 64-bit*
>
> Devices:
>
> - 2nd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics 3000/2000
> - 3rd Generation Intel® Core™ Processors with Intel® HD Graphics 4000/2500

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=21840

Comment: This driver is applicable to Intel Core processor not to Intel Atom. To my regret the driver does not install. `setup.exe` leads to error message box *This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software*. `igdlh64.INF` offers 4 drivers. For all of them I got a message: *The driver selected for this device does not support this version of Windows*.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 x64, 4Gb RAM and Intel GMA 36xx can work together! The downside is that GPU will eat 1Gb(!) of them. Still **3Gb** is better than 2.

1. Of course you need a working GPU 36xx driver. That's the easiest part. Just search for something like Intel_GMA_3150_WinXP_Vista_8-1_10_64bit.exe .
2. If you got an Atom CPU in a **notebook** then probably you should also put a custom BIOS firmware ([EEE PC 1025, for example](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Thread-REQUEST-Asus-eeepc-1025C?pid=69563#pid69563)) in it just to start the windows installation.
3. And the weirdest part — you need to go in safe mode, run **msconfig** and [**limit the RAM usage**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKUXc.png). The 3072 works well, but you definitely should try 4600 or so. There's something about addressing the room for GPU. Probably the north bridge cannot address more than 4.6Gb.

I'm also very interested in placing the 8Gb RAM module in it, and using the whole 4Gb block but don't have such a hardware currently. Hope, someone will place the feedback for the technique above :)

Answer (score -1):

Necro'ing this thread because of new info for better driver now available:

As the GMA 3600 etc is in fact a POWERVR SGX545 I did a site search of Imagination Technologies to see if they didn't perhaps have a better driver for the n2600.
https://www.google.co.za/search?ei=-XjQW6TYN4mJgQbWlJGgAw&q=site%3Awww.imgtec.com+POWERVR+SGX545+windows+driver+download&oq=site%3Awww.imgtec.com+POWERVR+SGX545+windows+driver+download&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4379546.4392400.0.4393542.17.17.0.0.0.0.444.4784.3-13j1.14.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.0.0....0.Pjz8X781k0E

They didn't 
BUT:
"...the big news for this release is the major upgrade of our PowerVR performance profiler, PVRTune Complete. We’re exposing more data than has been previously possible on mobile/embedded hardware, giving a major boost to your optimisation sessions..."
https://www.imgtec.com/blog/powervr-tools-and-sdk-2018-release-1-now-available/

ie:  The "military "Top Secret" data required to write a decent, optimized* driver now seems to be available!?

- Optimised:

  - DirectX10.1 API support
  - Enhanced support for DirectX10 Geometry
    Shaders
  - DirectX10 Data assembler support (Vertex, 
    primitive and instance ID generation)
  - Render target resource array support
  - Full arbitrary non power of two texture support
  - Full filtering support for F16 texture types
  - Support for all DirectX10 mandated texture formats
  - Sampling from unresolved MSAA surfaces
  - Support for Gamma on output pixels
  - Order dependent coverage based AA (anti-aliased 
    lines)
  - Enhanced line rasterisation

https://www.imgtec.com/news/press-release/imagination-technologies-announces-powervr-sgx545-graphics-ip-core-with-full-directx-10-1-opengl-3-2-and-opencl-1-0-capabilities/

I hope the info makes is way to a willing and able driver dev.