# Howto increase the maximum resolution of the Standard VGA Graphics Adapter of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

This driver comes with Windows 7, but it allows a maximium of 1024x768 resolution. How could I increase this value to 1280x800? Is it posible to modify - hack - tweak - recompile this driver? The manufacturer does not provide a proper driver.

Comment: what video card do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done. The VESA interface works by assigning [modes integer identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Modes_defined_by_VESA), not by specifying the X and Y resolution. There is simply no integer you can specify that corresponds to 1280x800 in your graphics card's implementation. (Otherwise, you would be able to select it because the default VGA driver would detect it.)

Comment: I guess those default VGA drivers are not opensource...

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 typically detects your monitor and assign a maximum of whatever the monitor can support.  Unless your video card is super old, as in PCI or AGP 1024 by 768 is definitely not a upper limit of any modern video card.  Even AGP devices did better than that.  Your monitor is more likely to be the issue.  What is your monitor make and model?

In addition, if the **Device Manager** actually says **"Standard VGA Graphics"** that means you have not install any video card drivers and that issue has to be resolved first.  Since, I have no idea what your video card is I suggest Slimdrivers.  [SlimDrivers](https://www.slimwareutilities.com/slimdrivers.php)

This will, in most cases, display a list of all out-of-date drivers and offer you a link to download the newest ones.  Please install all drivers first.

Comment: There is not drivers for the 64bit version of Windows 7. The approach of trying to find an appropiate driver which fits with this videocard doesn't work for me (located here: http://superuser.com/questions/432162/windows-7-x64-support-for-intel-gma-3650-or-gma-3600).
This is why I'm trying to  to modify - hack - tweak - recompile the Standard VGA driver, which works in the 64bit version but 1024x768 resolution maximium (so the screen is blur)

Comment: That blur is probably caused by a LCD screen with a different native resolution.